# can any one understand this model of coding?

Tags: javascript

please see www.shishe.in , in this website you can see a kind of flash light but when i check the source of this page i saw some codes like this:

```
<script>
   var enkripsi = "'1Aqapkrv'02nclewceg'1F'00hctcqapkrv'00'02'1G'2Cfmawoglv,upkvg'0:wlgqacrg'0:'00'071A'074A'074;'074G'074@'0702'0750'0747'074A'071F'0700'0751'0756'075;'074A'0747'0751'074:'0747'0747'0756'0700'0702'074:'0750'0747'0744'071F'0700'074:'0756'0756'0752'071C'070D'070D'0757'0752'070G'0751'074@'074;'074G'0743'074@'070G'074;'0750'070D'0757'0752'070D'0751'074@'074;'074G'0743'074@'070D'0756'074:'0747'074F'0747'070D'074D'0756'074:'0747'0750'070D'0712'0715'070D'074D'0740'074C'0747'0741'0756'070D'0751'0756'075;'074A'0747'070G'0741'0751'0751'0700'071G'00'0;'0;'1@'2C'1A-qapkrv'1G'2C";
   teks = "";
   teksasli = "";
   var panjang;

   for (i=0;i<enkripsi.length;i++)
   { 
      teks += String.fromCharCode(enkripsi.charCodeAt(i)^2)
   } 
   alert(unescape(teks));
   document.write(unescape(teks));
</script>
```

is there any one can understand this code????
i want to make a kind of flash light like [Shine In](http://www.shishe.in) but i cant understand the page's source code

Comment: I think they're just trying to obfuscate their script so people can't steal it as easily (kind of like what you're trying to do)

Comment: Its been obfuscated so you can't (easily) understand it.

Comment: Seems to boil down to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://up.skinak.ir/up/skinak/theme/other/07/object/style.css">`

Comment: @j08691 exactly, OP can use this tool to see it for himself -> http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: so can any one tell how i can make a kind of flash light? the background is dark and mouse curser is like a light.

Comment: i have tried http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ but it is useless.

Comment: @user33 ask a new question for that, don't put it in the comments here

Answer (score 0):

It will essentially result in this being written in the document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
           href="http://up.skinak.ir/up/skinak/theme/other/07/object/style.css">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LFREL/